# Call database class in student class to execute query

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

I have two main classes, Database & Student now I want to execute a query in `studentDetail()` method of Student Class. i.e.

But I am getting error that **"Cannot redclare class Db in database_Class.php line:3"**

**studnet_Class.php**

```
    include "database_Class.php";

 Class Student{
    private $db,$studentName;

    function __construct($DatabaseObj)
    {
        $this->db=$databaseObj;
    }

    public function studentDetail($ID)
    {
        $this->db->query("student",$ID);
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
$db= new Db();
$student= new Student($db);
```

Comment: Use `require_once` instead of `require`

Comment: What were ? require ?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you must have something like `require 'path/to/Db.php` **or** `include 'path/to/Db.php` . Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
include "database_Class.php";
```

by

```
include_once "database_Class.php";
```

This makes PHP including the file only if it hasn't included before.

I would further recommend to use `require_once` in favour of `include_once` to import a class. `require_once` will stop the script immediately throwing a fatal error if the file was not found. As a class file is an essential part of a program, only stopping the program immediately is a sufficient consequence.

I recommend to read the manual of

- [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
- [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)